# sql select with one value of two where

Tags: sql, join

This is the only place that I get all answer ;)

I want to select :

```
SELECT 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(il.Num_bloc)) AS Bloc, 
    RTRIM(LTRIM(il.num_colis)) AS Colis,
    cd.transporteur AS Coursier, 
    cd.origine AS Origine, 
    cd.destination AS Destinataire,
    cd.adresse AS [Adresse Destinataire], 
    cd.poids AS Poids, 
    il.Signataire, il.num_cin AS CIN, il.date_livraison AS [Date Livraison]
FROM  
    dbo.cd 
INNER JOIN 
    dbo.il ON cd.bloc = il.Num_bloc AND dbo.cd.colis = dbo.il.num_colis
WHERE 
    (il.Num_bloc = RTRIM(LTRIM(@ParamBloc))) 
    AND (il.num_colis = RTRIM(LTRIM(@ParamColis)))
```

In the way of getting result if the user put ether `@ParamBloc` or `@ParamColis`

Comment: Format your query, this is impossible to read...

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow: if you post code, XML or data samples, **please** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Answer (score 0):

Try using IsNull() function.

A simple query would go like this

```
Select * from yourTable
Where
  Num_bloc = ISNULL(@ParamBloc, Num_block) AND
  num_colis = ISNULL(@ParamColis, num_colis)
```

The second parameter would make the expression to true if the @parameter Bloc or Colis is null. This query would be useful for all 4 possible combination of these two parameter.

Comment: For this i am obliged to put NULL is the other field

Comment: When you say you'd pass either one, the other one defaults to NULL. However, the parameter needs to be NULLable, not the actual database field. The query never assumes the field to be NULL.